# ESP8266 get request from webpage returns Connectionr refused

Tags: get, arduino, esp8266

I want to be able to send data from a webpage to the esp8266 and control a pin, whenever I press the button on the webpage it returns the i address of the ESP and `CONNECTION REFUSED`. What am I doing wrong?

ESP code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
     }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("Netmask: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.subnetMask());
  Serial.print("Gateway: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());

}

int value = 0;


void loop() {
   HTTPClient http;

   http.begin("192.168.0.24:80");
   int httpCode = http.GET();

   if(httpCode > 0){
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println(payload);
    }
    http.end();
    delay(3000);

}
```

HTML website:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>ESP8266 toggle page</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <button id="3" class="led">Toggle pin 3</button>

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".led").click(function(){
            var p = $(this).attr('id');
            $.get("http://192.168.0.16:80", {pin:p});
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to make a webserver and host the website with toggle button on ESP8266 or you have hosted this website somewhere else on your network and you just need to make ESP8266 process your requests?

Comment: Yeah i want to be able to control and led from the click of my webpage

Comment: Your webpage hosted somewhere else than esp8266 but still on your network?

Comment: @Defozo I gave the esp8266 my desktops local ip and i gave the webpage the esp8266s local ip

Comment: OK, so basically you miss all the server part of esp8266 since you're configuring your esp8266 to act as a client rather than a server as for now.

Comment: @Defozo Can you elaborate?

Comment: See my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making your esp8266 to act as a client rather than a server. You should make your esp8266 accept requests rather than make one. Then, your esp8266 will be a server and your website a client. You will be able to make a request from your website to the server on your esp8266 and handle it.

To your includes add:

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
```

After includes before any functions add:

```
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
```

In your `setup()` add:

```
server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleTogglePin);
server.begin();
```

In your `loop()` add:

```
server.handleClient();
```

Before `setup()` add:

```
void handleTogglePin() {
    if (server.hasArg("pin")) { server.send(500, "text/plain", "Missing argument: pin"); return; }
    Integer pin = server.arg("pin").toInt();
    if (digitalRead(pin) == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to set your pin to output in `setup()` as well:

```
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
```

Comment: Good explanation @Defozo